# How do I create the following illustration in LaTeX?

Tags: image, latex

I have tried to create the following illustration in LaTex with poor results. The problem is that I am not able to determine the starting points nor ending points of the arrows how I want to. Any suggestions/hints how to do succeed in this?

[image: [Illustration of a game theoretic setup]

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should present your actual attempts to draw this illustration. The easiest way is to use the tikz package and the  'positioning' library that will allow tou to determine precisely the position of the end  points.

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible implementation using tikz, with the calc and positioning libraries

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={
      draw,thick,
    },
    label/.style={draw=none,midway,sloped,above,font=\small},
    myarrow/.style={->,thick} ,
    ]
    %poition upper and lower nodes
    \node[box] (gov) {Government};
    \node[box,below=4cm of gov,minimum width=3cm,dotted] (trans) {Transaction} ;

    % position first line extremity at, say, 1/3 gov node
    \coordinate (extr1) at ($(trans.north west)!0.33!(trans.north east)$) ;
    % then extremity 2 slightly at the right of extr1
    \coordinate (extr2) at ([xshift=2mm]extr1) ;

    % position bank vertically halfway gov/trans and centered wrt extr1 and extr2
    % due to some limitations in tikz parser, one must first define intermediate coords
    \coordinate (extr12) at ($(extr1)!0.5!(extr2)$) ;
    \coordinate (mid) at ($(gov)!0.5!(trans)$);
    \node[box] (bank) at (extr12 |- mid) {Bank};
    % draw first arrows
    \draw[myarrow] (extr1) -- (extr1 |- bank.south) node[label] {information};
    \draw[myarrow] (extr2 |- bank.south) -- (extr2) node[label] {monitoring};
    \draw[myarrow] (extr1 |- bank.north) -- (extr1 |- gov.south) node[label] {reporting} ;
    \draw[myarrow] (extr2 |- gov.south) -- (extr2 |- bank.north) node[label] {fines} ;
    % position last arrow midway from east border of bank and gov
    \coordinate (extr3) at ($(bank.east)!0.5!(gov.east)$) ;
    \draw[myarrow] (extr3 |- gov.south) -- (extr3 |- trans.north) node[label] {investigation} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to modify a couple parameters for the positioning that you want and add style to nodes/lines as required.

Answer (score 1):

Using `north` and `south` (and `phantom`) makes it ok vertically. Instead, I wanted to use `calc` TikZ library to also horizontally offset endpoints of arrows from nodes `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)` in a more elegant way but I didn't succeed:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, thick, sloped]
    \node [rectangle, very thick, draw, right] (a) at (0,6) {\large\textbf{Government}};
    \node [rectangle, very thick, draw, right] (b) at (0,3) {\large\textbf{Bank}};
    \node [rectangle, densely dotted, draw, right] (c) at (0,0) {\large Transaction};
    \node (d) at (.2,6) {\phantom{G}};
    \node (e) at (.2,3) {\phantom{B}};
    \node (f) at (.2,0) {\phantom{T}};
    \node (g) at (1.1,6) {\phantom{G}};
    \node (h) at (1.1,3) {\phantom{B}};
    \node (i) at (1.1,0) {\phantom{T}};
    \node (j) at (2,6) {\phantom{G}};
    \node (k) at (2,0) {\phantom{T}};
    \draw [->] (e.north) -- (d.south) node[pos=0.5, above] {reporting};
    \draw [->] (g.south) -- (h.north) node[pos=0.5, above] {fines};
    \draw [->] (f.north) -- (e.south) node[pos=0.5, above] {information};
    \draw [->] (h.south) -- (i.north) node[pos=0.5, above] {monitoring};
    \draw [->] (j.south) -- (k.north) node[pos=0.5, above] {investigation};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code results in:

[image: screenshot of output image]

Then you can tune this depending on your taste!

Comment: Thank you guys a lot for help! I must admit that I would not have got this done all by myself, so once again thx. :)

Comment: @Notlikethis Great! Please accept one of the answer, if the "problem" is "solved": you and the answerer gain reputation and the question will be tagged as answered :)